# Blazor Bootstrap -- Dropdown does not close when click outside element

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, blazor

In my Blazor Server app, I can't get the default Bootstrap dropdown behavior to work: I need the dropdown menu to disappear when I click anywhere outside the menu div.

I tried `@onfocusout` but if I click inside of one of the form inputs and then click the menu div again, the menu div disappears. I want it to persist in this use case. I just want to have the dropdown menu disappear when I click anywhere **other than** the dropdown button or its menu & corresponding menu contents.

My code is below - I have removed some form elements to make it easier to skim.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"
            id="userLoginMenuButton" @onclick="(() => this.showUserMenu=!this.showUserMenu)">
        <span>Click me!</span>
    </button>
    <div class="userLoginMenu dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right @(showUserMenu? "show":"")" 
             @onfocusout="() => this.showUserMenu = false" aria-labelledby="userLoginMenuButton">

        <form class="px-4 py-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleDropdownFormEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormEmail1" placeholder="email@example.com">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
        </form>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <AuthorizeView>
            <Authorized Context="Auth">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="" @onclick="(() => Logout())">Logout</a>
            </Authorized>
            <NotAuthorized>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="" @onclick="(() => Login())">Login</a>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeView>
    </div>
</div>
 
@code{

    private bool showUserMenu = false;

    public async Task Logout()
    {
        await ((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)AuthenticationStateProvider).MarkUserAsLoggedOut();
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("");
    }

    private void Login()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
}
```

Comment: side note: use just `@onclick="Login"` , especially for the async eventhandlers.

Comment: cool, will keep in mind. thanks

Comment: It works when you first click in the popup div. Only then can it lose the focus.

Comment: sorry, i'm not following your logic. do you have a suggestion for a better approach?

Comment: With your current code: click in the email box, then outside the menu. The logic is clear but a fix is beyond my bootstrap knowledge.

Answer (score 11):

You have to add an event `@onfocusout` to your DropDown button, this event will trigger a method we will name it `OutFocus`.

Because it triggers before the DropDown-item Click Event, we add a delay.

On Component:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" 
        @onclick="e => this.show = !this.show" 
        @onfocusout="OutFocus">
        DropDownText
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable @(show? "show":"")" >
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" >
            Item1
        </button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" >
            Item2
        </button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" >
            Item3
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

On code:

```
@code {

    private bool show = false;

    private async Task OutFocus() {

        await Task.Delay(200);
        this.show = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: This solution works well enough, @onmouseout is also a possible solution.

Comment: I do like this solution and thank you because it's very helpful for a navbar for example. However, it's sad that when the dropdown has some form inside it, it does not work as the dropdown menu disappears when the first form element is selected. Any ideas to work on this?

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 5, use **data-bs--auto-close**:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-auto-close="outside" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        ...
  </div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#options

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using `dropdown-toggle` in the drop down div? The [Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) shows dropdown menus with that property:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try switching your dropdown div to include `dropdown-toggle`. You shouldn't have to use a hacky workaround to achieve what you're trying to do. Also, make sure you have `Popper.js` installed as well.

Edit: Overlooked that you have `dropdown-toggle` on the button. You're also missing `aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"`. Try adding that.

Comment: I already have `aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"` in my actual code, but it did not affect the outcome.

Comment: A solution without C# might be the way to go. But I can't get this to work in a Blazor app.